# Offline routing in android

Tags: android, routes, openstreetmap, offline, osmdroid

I'm trying to develop an android app to work with offline maps. Thanks to some help, i've created the map, and i've been able to load the maps offline.

Now i'm trying to create routes, but i havent understood quite well how to do it.

If i'm correct, i have to use an [osm](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_XML) file that has node's, way's and relation's like described [here](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements).

My question is, how can i load this file's data to my app? I haven't been able to find any example of how to load this data to an app. All i've discovered is that this osm file can be converted to a smaller pbf file.

Can anyone explain me how to use this osm data? Can anyone give me an example? Or am i taking a wrong approach?

This code loads a OSM file with 700kb, but it doenst load mine because it has 99MB.

```
               // create the factory
           SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
           // create a parser
           SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();

           // create the reader (scanner)
           XMLReader xmlreader = parser.getXMLReader();

           // assign our handler
           xmlreader.setContentHandler(osmHandler);


           xmlInputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.lisboa);
           //xmlInputStream = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.milano);
           //xmlInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"MyMaps","Lissabon.osm"));

           xmlreader.parse(new InputSource(xmlInputStream));
           osmHandler.isLoaded=true;
```

I'm using osmbonuspack_v3.4 and osmdroid_3.0.10.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at Graphhopper library. As of now this seems to be the best library available for routing of OSM data in android.

https://github.com/graphhopper/graphhopper/blob/master/docs/android/index.md

Comment: it's not that good library, because it can work only with one graph (one country or city): https://discuss.graphhopper.com/t/how-to-set-routing-between-two-countries-load-two-gh-folders/3822

Answer (score 0):

Mapsforge has a library for compressing osm data and for reading it efficiently. It may not be your solution, but it'll be better than using a SAX parser

Comment: Mapsforge has nothing to do with routing